# performing part of a function once in lua

Tags: lua

i am currently playing ftb on minecraft and have gotten into the mod called computer craft, that uses lua as its programing language. i have written a basic script so far for clearing out rooms with 3 directions and any size. the directions are Right Left and Center. the center is for if the person wants the door to be the center of the room.
but i am having trouble performing a function i made along wit a bit of code one in another function once.

this is the function i want to perform once in another function

```
function hwd()
    for m = 1,w*0.5 do
       turtle.dig()
       echest()
       turtle.forward()
    end
end
```

this is the main function

```
function cntr()
    if d == "c" then
            for p = 1,w do
                length()
                turtle.turnRight()
                turtle.dig()
                echest()
                turtle.forward()
                turtle.turnLeft()
            end
    end
end
```

the part i need to perform once in on the first loop will look like this

```
turtle.turnLeft()
hwd()
turtle.turnRight()
```

after "for p = 1,w do" and before "length()"

i have the script working without the center part but need to ad this part.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

for the working script head to: http://pastebin.com/Uf5Li1Cy

for the script with the added center part head to: http://pastebin.com/AqZHQrFb

Comment: What is the error that you are currently getting?

Comment: Is the question here how to only call hwd() during the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: i am getting no error since the code isnt finished for me to execute it but yes and no Etan i want it to call the hole function but want hwd() to be called on the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

Does the loop always execute at least once? Then simply put that code right before the loop.

```
  -- do the special thing
  for p = 1,w do
```

If not, you can put it the loop guarded by a boolean:

```
  local didTheSpecialThing = false
  for p = 1,w do
     if not didTheSpecialThing then
        -- do the special thing
        didTheSpecialThing = true
    end
    ...
```

Or you could put it before the loop, with a check to see if it needs to be executed:

```
  if w > 0 then
    -- do the special thing
  end
  for p = 1,w do
```

Comment: Mud i thank you greatly. The last 1 worked perfectly now all i need to do is add in a mob/gravel detection bit and maybe block lite detect for torches. now i can do the finishing touches to my turtle script. i cant thank you enough.